# GetObject doesn't return a reference to Outlook if just started

Tags: vba, outlook

This code is from a larger block (a VBA Class running in MS Access).

```vb
Public Sub mrm_StartOutlook()
     
       Dim m_objOutlook As Outlook.Application
       Dim m_objNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
     
140    On Error GoTo PROC_ERR
     
150      Set m_objOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application") 'reliably fails if Outlook just opened.
         'Set m_objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 'reliably works
     
160      Set m_objNamespace = m_objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
     
170    MsgBox m_objOutlook.Name & ", " & m_objNamespace.Accounts.Item(1)
     
PROC_EXIT:
180    Exit Sub
     
PROC_ERR:
190    MsgBox "line " & Erl & " Error: " & Err.Number & ". " & Err.Description, , _
       "StartOutlook"
200    Resume PROC_EXIT
     
     End Sub
```

If Outlook has just started, line 150, using GetObject, triggers Error 429.
If I start Outlook manually, switch to the code window, wait for about 10 seconds, then call the sub above, it runs fine.
If I let Outlook open so that it's got the focus I can run the sub after about 5 seconds.

CreateObject always works.

This matters in a situation where I've checked if Outlook is open, found it isn't, opened it programmatically, and then run the sub.

It also matters where a user opens Outlook manually and then quickly runs my code.

I'm aware that any object variable pointing to Outlook is pointing to the same instance, but it would be good to get this to work reliably.

I suspect Outlook is not properly initialized, maybe the MAPI connection is not established. Is there a MAPI property that means - "ready and waiting" or similar?

I tried using timer pauses to give Outlook a chance to start properly. That seems clumsy. I either have to set the timer too long, and waste users' time, or too short and risk error 429.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off always using `CreateObject` - as you mentioned, since Outlook is a singleton, you'd always get the same object.

If you want to check whether Outlook was running before, check if `Application.Explorers.Count` and `Application.Inspectors.Count` are both zero.