# Find an email by its subject

Tags: vba, outlook

I receive an Outlook email every workday. I need to extract data from its attachment in the previous workday's email.

I used `.Find` to search for yesterday's email. VBA returned nothing.

```vb
Sub ExtractEmailData()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim myOlApp As Object, myNameSpace As Object, myFolder As Object, myitem As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim T1 As String, Subject As String
Dim yesterdayMail As Object, srcWB As Object, srcSheet As Object
Dim savePath As String, attachmentPath As String, attachmentName As String
Dim rowCount As Long

On Error Resume Next

    Set myOlApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If Err.Number = 429 Then Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    Set myNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    'Sorry I need to hide my email address below
    Set myFolder = myNameSpace.Folders("myemailaddress").Folders("Inbox") 
     
    ' Get T-1 date
        If Weekday(Date, 2) = 1 Then
            T1 = Date - 3
        Else
            T1 = Date - 1
        End If
        
    ' Format T-1 date
    T1 = Format(T1, "yyyymmdd")

    ' The subject is always like "KO, Expiries and Telekurs name for new issuance - 20230619"
    Subject = "KO, Expiries and Telekurs name for new issuance - " & T1
    Set yesterdayMail = myFolder.Items.Find("[Subject] = " & Subject)

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 
    'Sorry I need to hide part of the path
    savePath = "\\***\rf\Desktop\"
    
    If Not yesterdayMail Is Nothing Then
        attachmentName = yesterdayMail.attachments(1).DisplayName
        attachmentPath = savePath & attachmentName
        yesterdayMail.attachments(1).SaveAsFile attachmentPath
        Set srcWB = Workbooks.Open(attachmentPath)
        Set srcSheet = srcWB.Sheets(1)
        rowCount = srcSheet.Range("G2").End(xlDown).Row
        srcSheet.Range("G2:H" & rowCount).Copy ws.Range("A2")
        srcWB.Close
    End If
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: fyi. `On Error GoTo 0` just after `If Err.Number = 429 Then Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")`. You can see errors, if any. For **Outlook**, you could create without the error check. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63674163/getobject-doesnt-return-a-reference-to-outlook-if-just-started "since Outlook is a singleton, you'd always get the same object".

Comment: hi @niton, thanks for your comment. I don't quite understand what do you mean by singleton. Does it mean that I can delete "If Err.Number = 429 Then" in my code? thank you.

Comment: You can delete from `On Error Resume Next` to `If Err.Number = 429 Then` leaving only `Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")`. Now `On Error GoTo 0` is no longer needed.

Comment: A singleton means only one instance of Outlook is allowed. CreateObject acts the same as GetObject if the one allowed instance is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the subject terms in double-quotes *within* the string itself:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.find
>
> When filtering text fields, you can use either a pair of single quotes (') or a pair of double quotes (") to delimit the values that are part of the filter

Change your VBA to this:

```vb
subject = "KO, Expiries and Telekurs name for new issuance - " & T1

Dim query As String
query = "[Subject] = '" & subject & "'"

Set yesterdayMail = myFolder.Items.Find(query)
```

...or this:

(In VBA, a `""` *within* a string-literal is interpreted as a single `"`)

```vb
subject = "KO, Expiries and Telekurs name for new issuance - " & T1

Dim query As String
query = "[Subject] = """ & subject & """"

Set yesterdayMail = myFolder.Items.Find(query)
```

...assuming that your e-mail subjects won't ever contain a `'`' or `"` themselves, of course.

Comment: thank you so much it finally worked! Although I don't quite understand.